# Decoding base64 string return None

Tags: python, django, base64, django-3.0

I tried to generate uid for a user confirmation email.

```
'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
```

so, it's works nice, it returns something like "Tm9uZQ"

Then, when I tried to decode it, using `force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))`
it return None.

The next string

```
urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
```

also, return `b'None'`

I tried to google it, and see different implementations, but copy-paste code not works.

I write something like

```
    b64_string = uidb64
    b64_string += "=" * ((4 - len(b64_string) % 4) % 4)
    print(b64_string)
    print(force_text(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(b64_string)))
```

and the result still None:

```
Tm9uZQ==
None
```

I don't understand how the default decode doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"Tm9uZQ=="` is the `base64` encoding of the string `"None"`,

```py
>>> from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
>>> s = b'None'
>>> 
>>> b64encode(s)
b'Tm9uZQ=='
>>> b64decode(b64encode(s))
b'None'
>>>
```

It could be possible that some of your data is missing. E.g. user.pk is not set. I think that `force_bytes` is turning a `None` `user.pk` into the bytestring `b'None'`, from the Django source,

```py
def force_bytes(s, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'):
    """
    Similar to smart_bytes, except that lazy instances are resolved to
    strings, rather than kept as lazy objects.

    If strings_only is True, don't convert (some) non-string-like objects.
    """
    # Handle the common case first for performance reasons.
    if isinstance(s, bytes):
        if encoding == 'utf-8':
            return s
        else:
            return s.decode('utf-8', errors).encode(encoding, errors)
    if strings_only and is_protected_type(s):
        return s
    if isinstance(s, memoryview):
        return bytes(s)
    return str(s).encode(encoding, errors)
```

You might be able to prevent `None` being turned into `b'None'` by setting `strings_only=True` when calling `force_bytes`.

Comment: Your right, I tried to get the user from a request, but I use REST API for this functionality. Because user token is empty, I get AnonimousUser without Id (it's just None).